# How to include relationship in custom query in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to include the relationships of particular asset in custom queries written in `queries.qry` file, but couldn't find any solution, below is my code:

## Models

```
User
    o String id
    o String name
    o Integer age

Account
    id
    account_type
    --> User owner
```

## queries.qry

```
query selectAccountByType {
  description: "Select all accounts based on type"
  statement:
    SELECT com.rohitkhatri.bank.Account WHERE (account_type==_$account_type)
}
```

Now, what I want is, when I fetch the accounts, it should include the user relationship.

Here's what I have tried using `composer-rest-server`:

`/queries/selectAccountByType?account_type=saving&filter={"include":"resolve"}`

It returns the following error:

```
{'status_code': 500, 'message': 'Invalid or extraneous parameter filter has been specified'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter={"include":"resolve"}
```

is a loopback filter (exposed on the REST APIs only) - and not part of the Composer Query Language syntax.

see more here for examples of filters -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#filters
eg.

```
curl -g -X GET 'http://localhost:3000/api/Account?filter={"where":{"account_type":"saving"},"include":"resolve"}'
```

Comment: Getting the same error `{'status_code': 500, 'message': 'Invalid or extraneous parameter filter has been specified'}`

Comment: see the curl statement above - the Filter should be performed/applied to the asset class (not the Query endpoint) in the REST APIs.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve particular relationship but not all?

Comment: For an specific asset, if you resolve, you will resolve all relationships in the model (A resolve call will iterate over all the relationships). Its quite straightforward to discard the relationships you don't need of course.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking if there was a way to ignore that so It doesn't waste resource and takes less time.